# How to get and store the date and time of a post in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I'm currently doing a program that when a user posts or orders an item then the date and time will be posted in a html and stored in a MySQL table. As of now, i tried displaying the current date and time in my HTML file but it isn't stored in my MySQL table. Can anyone help me? And yes, i'm new at PHP and MySQL programming. :p

Comment: you should clear with your question, you want to select what...?

Comment: what i want is to get the exact date and time of a user's post and store it on a MySQL table.

Comment: can you give us an exemple of an insert-query

Comment: $query = "INSERT INTO orders (ord_date) VALUES '$ord_date'";

Comment: then go with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11518431/how-to-get-and-store-the-date-and-time-of-a-post-in-mysql/11518599#11518599

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that create a column in your table and take datetype like datetime and on displaying it retrieve that column value.

Comment: i already have a column named 'ord_date'. i've set it as a datetime type. it only displays 0000-00-00 00:00:00. and my HTML only displays the zeros.

Comment: change it to timestamp and set default value as CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.As i understand you don't want to insert it.what you want is automatically insertion.am i right?

Comment: yes, i want automatic insertion. it works now. thank you so much!

although my problem right now is that the time is running. what i want is the exact time and date of the post. and it won't change. :)

Comment: Use this it may work for you. ALTER TABLE TableName CHANGE colName colName TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Answer (score 1):

Lets try this.,

```
Alter your table that the field ord_date to current_timestamp.
```

It will insert to table the current server time,

OR

If you want to select current time, use query

```
select now().
```